# Who was the mentioned jedi in the Rogue One movie?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

I only saw the Rogue one movie in the theaters yesterday, so I don't remember the exact wording, but in the movie,

> during the attack on Sarif, the Alliance commanders discuss the possibility of calling a jedi friend. If i'm not mistaken, they refer to that person as "she".

Who did they mean? Leia? Or someone from the Rebels series?

Comment: I can't say for absolute certainty, but I'm pretty sure they didn't say 'her'. And considering it was Bail Organa, and what what we know happens at the beginning of ANH I think it's pretty safe to say it was Obi wan.

Comment: @BigTallJosh I cannot say that for certainty, I will have to watch the movie again, but I was actually baffled by that female pronoun. But user cmv14 in the comment below said: < I saw the movie, and I remember the question "can we trust her" being asked soon after mentioning the jedi comment. I thought this was Leia, but that "her" and the "jedi" were different characters > So I'm not the only one who remembers that reference, but it may well refer to another character, so that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now! Confusing two parts. Now I'm going to paraphrase here because I can't remember exact quotes. But  I'm fairly certain it's asked "What about your Jedi friend, can we get a message to them?" Something else is said and Bail implies he's sending someone (His daughter, Leia) and Mon Mothma replies "Can we trust her?" THEN that is when Bail says he says "With my life".

Comment: Ah, okay, that sounds very plausible. I have to watch the movie again, but i think you are right. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I've added an answer now :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think two parts of dialogue are being confused here.

I'm going to paraphrase here because I can't remember exact quotes. But I'm fairly certain the conversation goes as follows:

> *"What about your Jedi friend, can we get a message to them?"* Something is said about the Jedi friend has been in hiding since the Purge and Bail implies he's sending someone (We know from ANH this is his daughter, Leia). Mon Mothma replies *"Can we trust her?"* Bail replies *"With my life"*

From this and what we know from how *A New Hope* starts I think it's safe to say the Jedi in question is:

> Obi-Wan Kenobi

and the 'she' is:

> Leia Organa, Bail Organa's adopted daughter.

Comment: The 'something else' which was said is that the Jedi friend has been in hiding since the Purge.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkEdward I'll edit to make the answer better.

Comment: In the last spoiler tag who is the `his` supposed to be?

Comment: @Brad Bail Organa, I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 15):

The Alexander Freed novelization confirms that it was Obi-Wan Kenobi.

> It took Mon a moment to comprehend. Then she glanced to the closest other councilors and lowered her voice. **“Your friend,” she said. “The Jedi.”**
>
> Bail nodded again. **“He served me well during the Clone Wars and has lived in hiding since the Emperor’s purge.” He appeared to wait for Mon’s verdict, but she had nothing to offer. At last he finished, “Yes, I will send for him.”**
>
> *(Chapter 14)*

Based on what transpired in A New Hope, this was undoubtedly a reference to Obi-Wan

The "trust" thing was about Leia being sent:

> A Jedi, returning to fight against the Empire. It seemed an impossible thought, so Mon focused on what was not. “**Captain Antilles’s ship is docked with the Profundity for repairs, but it’s nearly ready to go**. The extraction should be simple; if it’s not, his skills will be an asset.”
> “My assessment as well,” Bail said.
> **“Whoever makes contact with the Jedi will have a terrible responsibility.”** Mon knew who Bail had in mind—it was clear in the tired lines of his face; in the fear of a man who had never previously feared the Emperor’s blackest vengeance. She was reluctant to doubt his decisions, but she needed to be certain. “You’ll need someone you can trust.”
> **“I would trust her with my life,” he said.**

Comment: The Freed novelisation doesn't confirm that it's Obi-Wan

Comment: @Valorum - if it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck....

Comment: In the immortal (and alas, now Legend) words of Luke Skywalker, what's a duck?

Comment: @Valorum - It depends on your point of view.

Comment: You can certainly draw an *inference* but what the book doesn't do is *confirm* his name. Imagine if this film wasn't a prequel, would you be able to identify who they were talking about from the source above?

Comment: @Valorum - i see what you mean, and technically, you're right; but i'm gonna use a legal standard of "preponderance of evidence" here.

Answer (score 12):

Leia and Obi-Wan.  Not sure why the Jedi reference was so specifically singular (hello...Yoda?) but this is the dialogue:

> **Mon**: Despite what the others say, war is inevitable
>
> **Bail**: Yes I agree, I must return to Alderaan to inform my people that there will be no peace. We will need every advantage
>
> **Mon**: Your friend, the Jedi
>
> **Bail**: He served me well during the clone wars, he has lived in hiding since the Emperor's purge, yes, I will send for him.
>
> **Mon**: You're gonna need someone you can trust
>
> **Bail**: I would trust her with my life.

Comment: Thank you for posting the dialogue! I saw the film twice and was confused by this both times - what threw me was that Bail refers to "her" without any antecedent, so I assumed it was referring to the Jedi. I didn't make the jump from "you're gonna need someone you can trust" to "I already have someone I can trust."

Comment: Now it makes sense. The Jedi is Obi-Wan Kenobi. But the "she" is the messenger Bail Organa needs to establish contact with Kenobi - and that is Leia Organa, whom he "trusts with his life". Thus establishing the hand-off to "Star Wars: New Hope" where Leia is passing a message to Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 4):

### The film's junior novelisation is explicit in its confirmation that Mothma and Bail Organa are talking about Obi-Wan Kenobi.

> *Mon Mothma glanced around to make sure no one was listening in. While the chamber had mostly cleared out, it was not entirely empty.
>
>   “Your friend,” she said in a low voice. “The Jedi.”
>
>   She was on the same wavelength as him. **Obi-Wan Kenobi had been a faithful friend long before he’d become one of the galaxy’s most hunted fugitives.** Bail didn’t want to disturb the man, but things had finally become that desperate.
>
>   “He served me well during the Clone Wars and has lived in hiding since the Emperor’s purge. Yes, I will send for him.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

### We can surmise from his emotional response that the "she" he was referring to was his own daughter, Leia Organa.

> *As usual, she was right. Bail couldn’t send just anyone to summon Kenobi from his exile. It would have to be someone strong, capable, and utterly committed to the Rebellion.
>
>   He could think of only one person. **If he could have, he would have chosen anyone else. But it would have to be her.**
>
>   Bail got to his feet and nodded at Mon Mothma once again. “I would trust her with my life.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - I've refrained from noting that this answer is the only one that *demonstrably* identifies Kenobi as the Jedi in question.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine if you note that.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so there are two reference points in this dialogue. Bail says that he will send for the Jedi which is a reference to Obi-Wan Kenobi. Then Mon says that Bail needs somebody that he can trust.. Meaning he will send for Obi-Wan via somebody he can trust.. and in this case somebody that he can trust with his life is Leia..

Answer (score 1):

**The jedi is Obi-Wan Kenobi**

Obi-Wan fought in the Clone Wars, as was mentioned in the dialogue. Leia is not a jedi. Luke is also not yet a jedi.

Comment: Did you see the movie? I'm not exactly sure, but i think, they said something in the lines of "Can you call your jedi friend? Can we trust her?" I'm almost sure they meant a female. So I think they meant someone from the Star Wars: Rebels series, probably Ahsoka Tano as the other answer suggested.

Comment: I saw the movie, and I remember the question "can we trust her" being asked soon after mentioning the jedi comment. I thought this was Leia, but that "her" and the "jedi" were different characters (although it might be Tano, in which case "her" and the jedi can be the same person). Leia would be taking custody over the death star plans and eventually contact Obi-Wan. Tano might be the jedi, but I feel more confident that Leia is not the jedi.

Answer (score -2):

Ashoka Tano was the Jedi (her) that fought in the Clone Wars along side Obi-wan and Anakin. She is also in contact with Bail in Star Wars Rebels.

Comment: canon series on Disney XD "Star Wars Rebels" - this is a good answer

Comment: Ashoka is no longer a jedi, however.

Comment: Ahsoka is also MIA as of Rebels Season 4; it's unlikely her return would be in the form of a brief mention in Rogue One.

Comment: @Jeffrywith1e -- Since there is no longer a *Jedi Order / Jedi Council* at all, if you want to maintain that **Ashoka Tano** is no Jedi, this technicality means no one is a Jedi. -- Still the correct answer is **Obi-Wan Kenobi** in this case. -- Also it's not clear to me that at this point in the timeline Ashoka is even alive... hard to say with the New Canon vs Legends issue.

Answer (score -3):

I believe the jedi they mention is Ahsoka Tano. From my knowledge she is the only female jedi alive at this time. And in the Ahsoka novel as well as the Rebel series, Ahsoka has contact with Bail Organa and is one of the founders of the rebellion. And in the Rogue One it is stated something like "and what of your jedi friend?" Something I don't remember here and then "she will come." I do not believe it could possibly be leia because she is no jedi. She had force capabilities but is not a jedi in the slightest.

Comment: The other answers seem to suggest that this is not the case.

Comment: This makes no sense. Rogue One is a prequel to *A New Hope*. Ahsoka Tano has no role in that movie. Bail Organa clearly trusts Leia with his life. Most importantly, you cite no canon sources to back this up.

Comment: Had the OP not confounded gender and Jedi your answer might be possible in the New Canon. Good thought though :)