# Length of time from Rogue One to Battle of Yavin

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

It seems to me that a surprisingly short time passes between

> Jyn Erso's rescue

and the destruction of the Death Star.

I'm not sure, but

> (disregarding the opening scene) Rogue One seems to take place in less than a week's time,

and A New Hope in maybe even less time, with

> a couple hours in between the films for the jump to Tattooine.

Can anyone point me to a specific timeline for

> Jyn's Rescue

during Rogue One until the Battle of Yavin?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147586/51379

Comment: Do you want to find the time from start to end of Rogue one? Or from end of Rogue One to ANH start?

Answer (score 5):

There is no 100% definitive canon proof of that, but according to creative team's unnamed source speaking to [Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-rogue-one-reshoots-disney-898562), ***10 minutes***.

> Rogue One focuses on the fabled mission hinted at in Star Wars: Episode IV — A  New Hope, that of a group of rebels stealing the plans to the Death Star. The plans later end up in the hands of Princess Leia, who transfers them to R2-D2.
>
> “This is the closest thing to a prequel ever,” a source tells THR. “This takes place just before A New Hope and leads up to the 10 minutes before that classic film begins. You have to match the tone!”

P.S. If you want to tack on the length of events in Episode IV, this was [discussed on SFF before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16141/976) - 6 days from Tatooine battle to Yavin battle.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking about amount of in-universe time for the whole movie, not just the ending

Comment: The OP is asking about the time not only to the start of episode 4 but the battle of yavin aka the fight against the death star there

Comment: @JasonBaker - I'm reading it as end to start, but [I asked just in case you're right](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147976/length-of-time-from-rogue-one-to-battle-of-yavin/147977#comment379172_147976).

Comment: @JasonBaker - also, if that's the case, the length of ANH is a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16141/976 and doesn't belong in this question.

Comment: Really, the whole question is a proper subset of that one. Ideally we'd update Plutor's CW answer there, and close this as a dupe of that. I doubt the OP is going to clarify, though; it's an unregistered account, and the pending edit suggests they've already lost access to it

Comment: @JasonBaker - feel free to un-dupehammer Valorum's dupe and dupehammer as you suggested. Seems like a good approach.

Comment: I don't have a star-wars dupehammer =(

Comment: @JasonBaker - this rate of RO answers, won't be too long :)