# How much time passes in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

From what I understood, Bodhi Rook was tortured and left starving by Saw Gerrera for several days in the Catacombs of Cadera. The movie also doesn't indicate how much time passes between the moment when Cassian hears from Tivik that an Imperial defector on Jedha has a message from Galen Erso for Saw Gerrera, and the moment when Jyn Erso, Galen's daughter and Saw's former Partisan, is released from the Wobani Labor Camp.

So how much time passes between Cassian's meeting with Tivik and the Battle of Scarif?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Approximately 7 days.

From the moment that Bodhi defects to the end of the film (and [the start of Star Wars: A New Hope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147586/how-much-time-passes-between-rogue-one-and-episode-iv?rq=1)) appears to be approximately 7 days. The times below are based on an assumption that there is a *one day travel time* between each of the planets seen in the film and borne out by Krennic's statement (at the end of the junior novelisation) that his ***week*** has been dreadful.

---

- **Day 1 - Bodhi defects to Saw's men on Jedha.**
- **Day 2 - Tivik speaks to Cassian and learns that Saw has the defector.**

> *“An Imperial pilot—one of the cargo drivers — **he defected yesterday,**”
> Tivik reported. “He’s telling people they’re making a weapon. The
> kyber crystals? That’s what they’re for. He brought a message. He’s
> got proof.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

- **Day 3 - Jyn rescued and taken to Yavin**

> ***Not even a day later, they delivered her to the headquarters of the
> Rebel Alliance** on a green moon orbiting a gas giant called Yavin.
> There they hauled her in front of what she guessed must have been
> their version of a court-martial.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

- **Day 4 - Jyn at Jedha**

> *It was **late into the night** when the band left the desert for the rocky
> slopes of a mountainside, then on from the mountain to the echoing
> corridors of a stone shelter. Cassian recognized the heavier tread of
> Chirrut’s partner at his side and risked a low murmur. **“We’re half a
> day out. A shrine?”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

- **Day 5 - Jyn at Eadu.**

> *BODHI ROOK couldn’t remember a time he’d been so terrified, and **the
> past few days had been filled with all sorts of nerve-racking things.**
> He’d escaped from the Empire with a secret message from Galen Erso,
> one of the top scientists in the galaxy. He’d delivered the message to
> Saw Gerrera—and been tortured for it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

and

> *Cassian thought back to the rumpled pile of a man he had found in the
> catacombs, malnourished and battered and deranged with trauma. **Less
> than a day later,** the man leading him through the canyons of Eadu was
> transparently terrified and far too eager to chat; but he was also
> doing his damnedest to feign normalcy on what looked likely to be a
> suicide mission. He was even doing a decent job of it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

- ***Approx* Day 6 - Jyn back at Yavin**
- ***Approx* Day 7 - Jyn at Scarif.**

> *KRENNIC HAD THOUGHT he’d already had the worst week of his life. Worse
> even than the one during which Galen Erso had abandoned their work on
> the Death Star and gone into hiding, leaving Krennic alone to head up
> the project.*
>
> *He’d already lost control of the Death Star to Grand Moff Tarkin. He’d
> been threatened by Darth Vader. And he suspected if he failed at his
> current task, he would probably be executed, perhaps by the Emperor’s
> own hand. But **this week kept finding ways to become even worse.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story – A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_%E2%80%93_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: How long had Jyn been in prison when she was liberated by Extraction Team Bravo?

Comment: @Lupin - Unclear. It only took the Rebels a day to find her and extract her. She was at a work camp, not a high security prison.

Comment: @Lupin - Looking over the novel, it feels like she'd been there for a few weeks, maybe a month or two.